# Qual a origem da palavra "alvinho"? O meu irmão é alvinho. A equipa principal é conhecida pelos alvinegros

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, origem-histórica, significado-em-contexto, adjetivos

Qual a origem da palavra "alvinho"?
Utilizado para indicar que é branquinho? O meu irmão é alvinho.

A equipa principal é conhecida pelos alvinegros

Comment: Pode ser considerado formal ou informal?

Comment: A minha primeira associação foi como diminutivo do nome Álvaro, talvez possam comparthar da mesma origem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Origem do latim [*albus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/albus), significa *branco*.

Em português pode ser encontrado como [*alvo*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/alvo) (sufixo *-inho* como diminutivo):

> adjetivo
>
> 6. Muito branco.
> 7. [Figurado]  Puro, límpido.

Além do contexto de futebol time alviverde, alvinegro. Alvinho no pouco que ouvi geralmente está relacionado como apelido ao nome *[Álvaro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvinho)* ou talvez o sobrenome *Alvim*, mas não como adjetivo relacionado a brancura de alguém (seja física ou espiritual).

Talvez alguém consiga esclarecer melhor este uso com pessoas, em outras regiões ou contextos.

Comment: puro, límpido...

Answer (score -1):

alvinho vem de ALVI que significa branco.

Comment: Boa tarde. É importante fundamentar a resposta para ficar tudo mais claro